# How to implement interaction between three or more fragments in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass information(latLng) from two fragments to a third one.

### FirstFragment

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, InitializeHelperInterface {
private lateinit var sendLatLngFromListener: OnSendLatLngListener

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        sendLatLngFromListener = context as OnSendLatLngListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException){
        throw ClassCastException(
            "$context должен реализовывать интерфейс OnSendLatLngFromListener")
    }
}

override fun moveCamera(latLng: LatLng, zoom: Float, title: String){

    sendLatLngFromListener.onSendLatLngFrom(latLng)
```

### SecondFragment

```
private lateinit var sendLatLngToListener: OnSendLatLngListener

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    try {
        sendLatLngToListener = context as OnSendLatLngListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException){
        throw ClassCastException(
            "$context должен реализовывать интерфейс OnSendLatLngToListener")
    }
}

override fun moveCamera(latLng: LatLng, zoom: Float, title: String){

    sendLatLngToListener.onSendLatLngTo(latLng)
```

### Interfaice

```
interface OnSendLatLngListener {

fun onSendLatLngFrom(latLngFrom: LatLng) {
}

fun onSendLatLngTo(latLngTo: LatLng){
}
```

}

### MapsActivity

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnSendLatLngListener{

private lateinit var latLngFrom: LatLng
private lateinit var latLngTo: LatLng

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

    val pageAdapter: FragmentStateAdapter = TabHandler(this)
    viewpager?.adapter = pageAdapter

    val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(
        tabs, viewpager
    ) { tab, position ->
        when(position){
            0 -> tab.text = "Откуда"
            else -> tab.text = "Куда"
        }
    }
    tabLayoutMediator.attach()

    button()
}

override fun onSendLatLngFrom(latLngFrom: LatLng) {
    this.latLngFrom = latLngFrom
}

override fun onSendLatLngTo(latLngTo: LatLng) {
    this.latLngTo = latLngTo
}

private fun button(){
    route_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_route)
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.routeFragment) as RouteFragment
        fragment.setLatLng(latLngFrom, latLngTo)
    })
}
```

}

But the button method is not passed LatLng from the fragments when the application starts.

### Exception

> lateinit property latLngTo has not been initialized

Please tell me how to do it right.

Comment: Does `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` lives inside `MapsActivity` ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf No, how should it be?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the method `sendLatLngToListener.onSendLatLngTo(latLng)` even called before you press the button? I would recommend to use the debugger, set a breakpoint at this method and find out.

Comment: I do not know why, but when I checked through the debug everything started working. I still don't understand what it was, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fragment Result API:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
    // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
    val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
    // Do something with the result
    }
}

button.setOnClickListener {
   val result = "result"
   // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
   setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
}
```

For the complete list of ways to communicate between fragments and also between fragments and activities see the doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: Thanks. I will try your way too, but for now my code started working. I hope this will also help those who encounter this problem.